# Bash find and expression

Tags: linux, bash, find

Is there some way to make this working?

pFile=`find ${destpath} (( -iname "${mFile##*/}" )) -o (( -iname "${mFile##*/}" -a -name "*[],&<>*?|\":'()[]*" )) -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`

i need pFile return the number of file with the same filename, or if there aren't, return 0.
I have to do this, because if i only use:

pFile=`find ${destpath} -iname "${mFile##*/}" -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`

It doesn't return if there are same filename with metacharacter.

Thanks

EDIT:

"${mFile##*/}" have as output file name in start folder without path.

echo "${mFile##*/}" -> goofy.mp3

Exmple
in start folder i have:

goofy.mp3 - mickey[1].avi - donald(2).mkv - scrooge.3gp

In destination folder i have:

goofy.mp3 - mickey[1].avi -donald(2).mkv -donald(1).mkv -donald(3).mkv -minnie.iso

i want this:

echo pFile -> 3

With:

pFile=`find ${destpath} -iname "${mFile##*/}" -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`

echo pFile -> 2

With:

pFile=`find ${destpath} -name "*[],&<>*?|\":'()[]*" -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`

echo pFile -> 4

With Same file name i mean:
/path1/mickey[1].avi = /path2/mickey[1].avi

Comment: Geez! Your line is pretty, say, interesting ^^ Guess it'd be easier for you to give an input and output example.

Comment: You said _I need pFie to return the number of files with the same name_. That would be `find . -name "$my_name" | wc -l`, but it appears your definition of the same name differs from mine. Can you give a more thorough explanation what you mean by the _same name_?

Comment: /path1/mickey[1].avi and /path2/mickey[1].avi have the same file name.
this i mean with the same name
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your intended semantics of `${mFile##*/}`, however looking at your start/destination folder example, I have created the following use case directory structure and the script below to solve your issue:

```
$ find root -type f | sort -t'/' -k3
root/dir2/donald(1).mkv
root/dir1/donald(2).mkv
root/dir2/donald(2).mkv
root/dir2/donald(3).mkv
root/dir1/goofy.mp3
root/dir2/goofy.mp3
root/dir1/mickey[1].avi
root/dir2/mickey[1].avi
root/dir2/minnie.iso
root/dir1/scrooge.3gp
```

Now, the following script (I've used `gfind` to indicated that you need GNU `find` for this to work, but if you're on Linux, just use `find`):

```
$ pFile=$(($(gfind root -type f -printf "%f\n" | wc -l) - $(gfind root -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort -u | wc -l)))
$ echo $pFile
3
```

I'm not sure this solves your issue, however it does print the number you expected in your provided example.